# Switching between significant-location-change monitoring and location-updates monitoring based on application state

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

We use significant-location-change monitoring to know about our user's whereabouts when the app is not running. This data is based on cellular towers signals and therefore is not very accurate. We would like to use more accurate data whenever it is possible, that is, when the app is active or running in the background.

The question is, should I use "startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges" and "startUpdatingLocation" at the same time, or, should I switch between those two methods? And if the second option is better, what app delegate events should I use in order to perform the necessary switch?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you want to support a feature that needs continuous high precision location stream, its best to avoid using the high accuracy GPS data via `startUpdatingLocation` all the time.

I understand from your question that you intend to use more accurate location only at certain points of interest, when your app is woken up. In that case, the second approach of switching-on the more accurate location data only when needed, would be a better idea.

`locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` in your `CLLocationManager` delegate would be a good point to start this in your case. Remember that significant location change monitoring API wakes up the system at least once every 15 minutes, even if there are no location changes, until it is explicitly stopped. So one must use it with care.

Instrumenting accurate location tracking while making sure that you don't eat up all of the phone battery is a non-trivial problem to solve. You may want to give third party SDKs like [Hypertrack](https://www.hypertrack.com/), which specialise in this, a try.